# Destroying Child component in Blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

**Parent Component**

**CounterParent.razor:**

```
@page "/counter"

<h3>Parent Component</h3>

<p>Counter Value: @currentCount</p>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Counter</button>
<br />
<br />
<button @onclick="EnablePopup" class="btn btn-danger">Visible</button>
<br />
<hr />
<br />

<p>Hide Popup view</p>
<button class="btn btn-dark" @onclick="() => _bVisible = false">Hide</button>

@if(_bVisible)
{
    <Popup ClientX="@strClientX" ClientY="@strClientY"></Popup>
}

@code
{
    private int currentCount;
    private bool _bVisible;
    private string? strClientX;
    private string? strClientY;

    public void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }

    void EnablePopup(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        strClientX = $"{e.ClientX.ToString()}px";
        strClientY = $"{e.ClientY.ToString()}px";

        _bVisible = true;
    }
}
```

**Child Component**

**Popup.razor**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages
@implements IDisposable

<div style="position: absolute; top: @ClientY; left: @ClientX; border: solid 1px #da70d6;background-color: #db7093">
    <h3>Child Component Two</h3>
    <p>This is popup component</p>
</div>

@code 
{
    [Parameter]
    public string? ClientX { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string? ClientY { get; set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

Here, i wanted to destroy the `Popup.razor` component. Whenever setting the `_bVisible = true`, does Blazor create a new instance every time for the `Popup.razor` component (Initially it creates a new instance)?

How to destroy the child component in Blazor?

Does Popup component destroy after setting `_bVisible = false;`?

Comment: You can answer this yourself by putting a breakpoint or a WriteLine in the Dispose() method.

Comment: @HH Popup.razor Dispose() method gets called while hiding the component, but its for clearing the Unmanaged resources in Popup component. My question is, does it really clear the Popup instance?

Comment: a) Why do you care?  b) Yes (it becomes 'available for garbage collection'). Unless you keep a reference around.

Comment: @HH a) I have to care because different kind of popup will be created based on the table column type. So, just wanted to clear myself whether it really destroys or not. 
b) Thanks for your explanation, its clear now. Is it possible to see the process in the code that how the Popup instance gets destroyed?

Comment: Forget about "destroy".  Main point is that Blazor will forget your component and not re-use it after a Dispose. A general dotnet convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can verify by adding this to your Popup:

```html
 <h3>Child Component Two, instance @GetHashCode()</h3>
```

The dotnet HashCode is a quick way to check an instance's identity. Different number: different instance.

Comment: Good point, I hadn't thought of using the HashCode.

Answer (score 1):

@HH has answered your main questions in the comments.  He should add an answer here which you should accept.

You can track instances of components like this:

```cs
@page "/"
@using System.Diagnostics;

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

@code {
    private Guid ComponentUid { get; init; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        var message = $"Creatimg new instance of Index with ID:{ComponentUid}";

        Debug.WriteLine(message);
        // Or
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

And also add logging to `IDispose/IAsyncDispose` if you wish.

In your code, if the component is rendered when `_bVisible` is false, `PopUp` [if an instance exists] is no longer part of the RenderTree.  The renderer "de-allocates" it by running Dispose/DisposeAsync [if the component implements `IDispose/IAsyncDispose`] and then drops it's reference.  The GC does the cleaning up [as long as no one else holds a reference to it].

In many cases you can use `using` to handle resource disposal at a method level: the  most common being `DbContexts` from a `DbContextFactory`.